# Trigonometric system with different coefficients

Tags: trigonometry

I have a trigonometric system as below and I want to solve it for $x$.

\begin{gather}
A\cos(x)+B\cos(2x)+C\sin(2x)  = D \\
-C\cos(2x)-A\sin(x)+B\sin(2x) = F
\end{gather}

Can anyone suggest a solution?
Regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The unknown is just one. You should solve the first equation for $x$ and verify if that solution verifies the second (or viceversa).

Comment: I had tried sin2x = 2 sin x Cos x and Cos 2x = 2cos^2 x-1 and solve the first equation and then applied the solution for the next one. But it was not satisfying me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the two equations as
$$\sqrt{B^2+C^2}\cos(2x-a) = D-A\cos x $$
$$\sqrt{B^2+C^2}\sin(2x-a) = F+A\sin x $$
with $a = \tan^{-1} \frac CB$. Square and add the two equations
$$B^2+C^2= D^2+F^2 +A^2 +2A(F \sin x - D\cos x)\\
= D^2+F^2 +A^2 +2A\sqrt{D^2+F^2} \sin (x-b)$$
with $b= \tan^{-1} \frac DF$. Now, it should be straightforward.

Comment: Very good, thanks Quanto!!

Comment: @MelisaKarimi - no problem

Answer (score 0):

Note $(1)$ the first equation and $(2)$ the second. Multiplying $(1)$ by $C$ and $(2)$ by $B$ the sum of two resulting equations give $$A\cos(\theta-x)+\cos(2x)=\frac{BD-CF}{B^2+C^2}=M$$ Similarly you get $$A\sin(\theta-x)+\sin(2x)=\frac{CD-BF}{B^2+C^2}=N$$ where $\sin(\theta)=\dfrac CB$. Now taking the square and adding you get
$$A^2(1)=(M-\cos(2x))^2+(N-\sin(2x))^2$$ so you have
$$M\cos(2x)+N\sin(2x)=\frac{M^2+N^2+1-A^2}{2}$$ which is a standard equation you can solve. In fact you do have
$$\sin(\phi+x)=\frac{M^2+N^2+1-A^2}{2(M^2+N^2)}$$ where $\sin(\phi)=\dfrac{M}{M^2+N^2}$.

Comment: Thank you Piquito! Nice idea..

Comment: You are welcome.